# Display number of rows on footer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to do a simple thing to my app.
[image]

Take a look at my main ViewController:

```
class Page1: UITableViewController {
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Shared.instance.employees.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1

        cell.nameLabel.text = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].name
        cell.positionLabel.text = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].position

        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? Page2,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destination.newPage = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

So, what function do I have to add to show the number of rows as I add more and more itens?

Differences between with and without delegates:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the stuff doing this -> I inserted a simple label below the Prototype Cell, like this:
[image]

Then, I just put this on `viewDidLoad`:

```
    footerLabel.text = String(Shared.instance.employees.count) + " employees"
```

By the way, thanks Mr vadian for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Just implement

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Total \(Shared.instance.employees.count) rows"
}
```

If you want to customize the title you have to implement `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` and return a view for example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 30.0))
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text =  "Total \(Shared.instance.employees.count) rows"
    return label
}
```

Side-note: Instead of calling `Shared.instance.employees` multiple times use a temporary variable:

```
let employee = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel.text = employee.name
cell.positionLabel.text = employee.position
```

Comment: Working great! Thanks! But there is how to do it more likely the Phone app on iOS? I mean, higher and centralized

Comment: Then you have to implement `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` instead and return a custom view which can also be just an `UILabel`.

Comment: Do I have to create another `Prototype Cell`? I didn't get what do I have to return exactly.

Comment: No, `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` is a delegate method like `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:`. You have to return an `UIView` instance, the view can contain whatever you like but you are  responsible for the appearance (size, font, alignment etc.)

Comment: A string is not a view and `UIView` and `String` are not related at all. I updated the answer.

Comment: Now I got it perfectly!! I thought I had to "choose" one of them function, not using both. lol THANKS!!!!!

Comment: Indeed you **have** to choose one of the delegate methods, however if `viewForFooterInSection` is implemented then `titleForFooterInSection` is ignored.

Comment: This is weird, because only worked with both methods. I just updated the question.

Comment: On my machine it works also with only `view...` implemented, but never mind, then implement both.

Comment: If you implement `viewForFooterInSection` you must also implement `heightForFooterInSection`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy that unravels the mystery. I had implemented `heightForFooterInSection`.